# Fill Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to Fill this type of Array in Javascript..

```
var neighborhoods = [
    {lat: 52.511, lng: 13.447},
    {lat: 52.549, lng: 13.422},
    {lat: 52.497, lng: 13.396},
    {lat: 52.517, lng: 13.394}
];
```

I have tried this way but its not happening

```
$.each(result.geoloc, function(index,geoloc) {
    geoloc_split=geoloc.Geoloc.split(',');
    // alert(geoloc_split[0]+","+geoloc_split[1]);
    var lat="lat: "+geoloc_split[0];
    var lng = "lng: "+geoloc_split[1];
    neighborhoods.push(lat,lng);
    geoloc_split="";
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are pushing only values to array. You need to push new object (e.g. create it with object literal). Furthermore you need to convert string values to float:

```
var lat = parseFloat(geoloc_split[0]);
var lng = parseFloat(geoloc_split[1]);
neighborhoods.push({
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng
});
```

In ES6 you can use property value shorthand:

```
neighborhoods.push({lat, lng});
```

Comment: Its giving me error

InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this :

```
$.each(result.geoloc, function(index,geoloc) {
     geoloc_split=geoloc.Geoloc.split(',');

     neighborhoods.push({
         lat:parseFloat(geoloc_split[0]),
         lng:parseFloat(geoloc_split[1])
     });

     geoloc_split="";
});
```

Because your neighborhood array is an array of object you need to fill it with objects .

Comment: Its giving me Error

InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Comment: Thanks @Marox Tn,
But I am Still getting the same Error
I have also alerted the values of geolocations, they are as expected but still :(

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(geoloc)` inside the `$.each` ?

Comment: Object {Geoloc: "-38.1024466,145.1700861"}
showmap:175 Object {Geoloc: "-37.9996694,145.1121534"}
showmap:175 Object {Geoloc: "-37.9957947,145.1101839"}
showmap:175 Object {Geoloc: "-38.0030245,145.1184165"}
showmap:175 Object {Geoloc: "-38.0030245,145.1184165"}
showmap:175 Object {Geoloc: "-37.8176861,144.8396454"}